# How to resolve the problem of snapshot in new Flutter update?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0chUi.png)I am having problem on snapshot.data.I saw documentation there written to use snapshot[''] i also use that but i am having problem this says
'The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.dart'

```
 return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!['definitions'].length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListBody(
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                      elevation: 8,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: ExpansionTile(
                          onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) =>
                              setState(() => this.isExpanded = expanding),
                          // backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          leading: snapshot.data!['definitions'][i]
                                      ['image_url'] ==
                                  null
                              ? CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                                  maxRadius: 25,
                                )
                              : CircleAvatar(
                                  maxRadius: 25,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot
                                      .data['definitions'][i]['image_url']),
                                ),
                          title: Text(
                            _controller.text.trim() +
                                "  (" +
                                snapshot.data['definitions'][i]['type'] +
                                ")",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: isExpanded
                                  ? FontWeight.w400
                                  : FontWeight.w300,
                              color:
                                  isExpanded ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I am getting error on                                                              itemCount: snapshot['definitions'].length,                            
                                                                                              
  Here It says:                                                                                      The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: Your screenshot is completely different from your code sample. The code sample doesn't even use `snapshot[]`. Maybe you can reduce the code sample to minimum reproducible version, Nobody has a desire to debug your whole application. Try to be specific about your problem.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @HerbertPoul My Screen Shot shows the error log of code . I am having problem in retrieving data via snapshot. I don't understand how to documentation of snapshot.                                        snapshot.data!['definitions'][i]
                                          ['image_url'] ==

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer after reading the documentation and from YouTube video I need to use                      [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl5ad.png)

```
 body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: _stream,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Type a word to get its meaning ',
              style: Te
```